# Lock Timeouts with low Lock Waits

Tags: sql-server-2012

On a production SQL Server 2012 database we are getting some odd locking statistics that I don't understand.

- Lock Waits/Min: 0.2
- Lock Timeouts/Min: 197.4
- Deadlocks/Min: 0.0

@@lock_timeout is set to -1

How can I have Lock Timeouts without having Lock Waits? I recently added some missing indexes, could that be affecting these numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are monitoring a `Lock Timeouts/sec` Performance Monitor counter or perhaps querying [sys.dm_os_performance_counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187743.aspx) directly.  The `Lock Timeouts/sec` class for Profiler has the following notes in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189107.aspx):

[image: Lock Timeouts/sec]

Most likely the vast majority of the events you are seeing are explained that way.  Try monitoring [Lock:Timeout (timeout > 0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190916.aspx) instead.